# Unable to set a range into the Listbox.RowSource method or Listbox.List method

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

When the line reaches `lbxFoilInfoDisplay.RowSource = "tblFoilInfoHelper!A1:" & Col_Letter(TotalColumnsCount("Foil Purchases.xlsm", "List_Box")) & TotalRowsCount("Foil Purchases.xlsm", "List_Box", "tblFoilInfoHelper")` I get the error:

[image]

When I try to replace it with:
`lbxFoilInfoDisplay.List = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List_Box").Range("A1:" & Col_Letter(TotalColumnsCount("Foil Purchases.xlsm", "List_Box")) & TotalRowsCount("Foil Purchases.xlsm", "List_Box", "tblFoilInfoHelper"))`, I get the error:

[image]

I believe the name of the table is correct as shown in the image below:

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Dim filterRangeFoilProfile As Range, filteredRangeFoilProfile As Range
Private Sub cbxSupplier_AfterUpdate()
Dim Supplier_col As Long

lbxFoilInfoDisplay.RowSource = vbNullString
Supplier_col = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Foil Profile").ListObjects("tblFoilProfile").ListColumns("SUPPLIER").Index
filterRangeFoilProfile.AutoFilter Field:=Supplier_col, Criteria1:=cbxSupplier.Text
On Error Resume Next
Set filteredRangeFoilProfile = Intersect(filterRangeFoilProfile, filterRangeFoilProfile.Offset(1, 0)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not filteredRangeFoilProfile Is Nothing Then
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Foil Profile").ListObjects("tblFoilProfile").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List_Box").Cells(2, 1).PasteSpecial
    lbxFoilInfoDisplay.RowSource = "tblFoilInfoHelper!A1:" & Col_Letter(TotalColumnsCount("Foil Purchases.xlsm", "List_Box")) & TotalRowsCount("Foil Purchases.xlsm", "List_Box", "tblFoilInfoHelper")
    'lbxFoilInfoDisplay.List = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List_Box").Range("A1:" & Col_Letter(TotalColumnsCount("Foil Purchases.xlsm", "List_Box")) & TotalRowsCount("Foil Purchases.xlsm", "List_Box", "tblFoilInfoHelper"))
End If

End Sub
```

User-Defined Functions (to add context):

1.)

```
Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
    Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

2.)

```
Function TotalRowsCount(WBString As String, WorksheetNameString As String, TableNameString As String) As Long

Dim Total_columns As Long
Dim i As Long

Total_columns = Workbooks(WBString).Worksheets(WorksheetNameString).ListObjects(TableNameString).ListColumns.Count

ReDim Rows_count(1 To Total_columns) As Long
For i = 1 To Total_columns
    With Workbooks(WBString).Worksheets(WorksheetNameString).ListObjects(TableNameString).ListColumns(i).Range
    Rows_count(i) = .Find(What:="*", _
        After:=.Cells(1), _
        Lookat:=xlPart, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
        MatchCase:=False).Row
    End With
Next i
TotalRowsCount = WorksheetFunction.Max(Rows_count)

End Function
```

3.)

```
Function TotalColumnsCount(WBString As String, WorksheetNameString As String) As Long

Dim lastColumn As Long
lastColumn = Workbooks(WBString).Worksheets(WorksheetNameString).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
TotalColumnsCount = lastColumn

End Function
```

Comment: Can i suggest to do a `Debug.Print "tblFoilInfoHelper!A1:" & Col_Letter(TotalColumnsCount("Foil Purchases.xlsm", "List_Box")) & TotalRowsCount("Foil Purchases.xlsm", "List_Box", "tblFoilInfoHelper")` and see that your range gets generated properly? Do this before or instead of the problem line of course.

Comment: @DarXyde I got `tblFoilInfoHelper!A1:K4` as the output i'm not sure if I did the `RowSource` method correctly but I believe it is

Comment: Try using the sheet name instead of the table name? ie: `lbxFoilInfoDisplay.RowSource = "List_Box!A1:" & Col_Letter(TotalColumnsCount("Foil Purchases.xlsm", "List_Box")) & TotalRowsCount("Foil Purchases.xlsm", "List_Box", "tblFoilInfoHelper")`

Comment: @DarXyde Oh yes... That works didn't realize that was the issue. I had a worksheet named `Table` in the reference workbook I was using I confused it as a table. Thanks

Comment: Glad i could help... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the sheet name instead of the table name. ie: **"List_Box!A1:" &...**

```
lbxFoilInfoDisplay.RowSource = "List_Box!A1:" & Col_Letter(TotalColumnsCount("Foil Purchases.xlsm", "List_Box")) & TotalRowsCount("Foil Purchases.xlsm", "List_Box", "tblFoilInfoHelper")
```

Might find some use for this... or not. You can do this using the table as well, but you still need to use the Sheetname in order to get the address of the cells. ie.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range.Cells(3, 1).Address
```

This is useful if you need to refer to specific cells in your table, and care less where the table is located. However this is only to help you build the address part - and not to replace the sheet name with the table name.